# Screen hight with (UIScreen) is fine in iPad but wrong in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am developing a game where a background is moving at the back. I sat the background hight using the below code. It is working fine with iPads but with iPhones it is not taking the proper hight of the screen; instead it is in the middle of the screen with almost half the hight of the screen! The application is only working in portrait orientation. This is for xCode 8 & SWIFT 3

Please check below the code I am using for the background
 hight:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds
background1.size.height = screenSize.height
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use UIScreen.main.bounds directly if you just want Screen size

Comment: sometimes this happens when you remove the main storyboard from the project general setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue but using a (workaround) rather than resolving the root cause as I could not identify it.

First I have noticed that when sizing the hight of the screen I have 2 conditions:

1. below code will work with all iPhones but not iPads:

   background1.size.height = self.frame.height
2. below code will work with all iPads but not iPhones:

   background1.size.height = screenSize.height

So since the minimum hight of screen of iPads is 1024; I used the below code to first check if it is iPad use condition 2 and if iPhone use condition 1 as follow:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        if screenSize.height < CGFloat(1024) {
            background1.size.height = self.frame.height  ////for iphone
        } else {
           background1.size.height = screenSize.height ////for ipad 
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what your case is.But it happens in iPhone 5+ devices due to launch screen size.Normally it behaves like iPhone 5 screen size even with iPhone 6,iPhone 6+.

Now the soultion.

1.You can use the default **launch screen storyboard** to avoid the problem.

2.You have to add every sizes for iPhone screen size (320*480,640*960,640*1136,768*1334,1242*2208).please add also iPhone 7,7+ sizes too.

3.You can use asset Catalogs for launch screen.

If thats the case for you please use above solution.It should work.